# MFMailComposeViewController's Send and Cancel Buttons are not appearing

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

for some reason the send and cancel buttons are not appearing, i even pasted the following code at the start of the application in appdelegate just when the app launches but still its not working. Can anybody help, thanks

```
mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailController setToRecipients:[strToEmailAddresses componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
        [mailController setSubject:@"An Invite from MyGuide"];
        [mailController setMessageBody:@"Join me and your other friends now for free." isHTML:NO];

        if(mailController == nil)
            NSLog(@"Nil");
        else
            [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you try replacing inviteFriendViewController with self?

Comment: also, check that you added MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate to the header file (although i think you should have seen other errors if you had not done so before)

Comment: still not working, dont know what is making the Send and Cancel buttons disappearing :(

Comment: Is your app a nav based app because i was having problems with that aswell because i didnt push it on to the stack correctly. Also just like TommyG's reply it needs to be delegated properly.

Comment: @Kazmi I'm having the same problem, did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I have stumbled upon this problem myself, and for me the answer was that the buttons had a white tint (because my app has white as tintColor) which made them invisible with the navigation bar background! So they were actually there, but the color made them invisible. If this is your problem as well, you'll need to temporarily set the tintColor of the navigationBar to something else when the MailComposer is pushed on to the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the navgationBarHieedn be NO,which is the property of the navigationController of MFMailComposeViewController.

And I have this problem in a category of "UINavigationController" which sets navigationBarHidden as YES when pushing a new viewController.After these code edited,the cancel buttons appeared;